How to identify which log file is contributing index size most in ElasticSearch?
We have an ElasticSearch cluster in the cloud and our application generates multiple different logs, a dozen different log files everyday. All of the logs are ingested into same index in elasticsearch with daily rotation. We find now the logs are huge in ElasticSearch and need to find out which log files is contributing most from which server it is coming from.
What is the query I can use to identify the top 10 servers and top 10 log files by size? This is the more like the counting size of a column by grouping them in SQL databases, however, I am not very familiar with Elastic version of it.
Please help with Elastic way (query API) for this case.
Thanks

Can you show a sample log file from that index?

You can use Elasticsearch term aggregation to see top 10 results by count. By size is more harder and expensive, so I suggest use by count. doc_count in the response body will show you the result.
#top 10 test_field result
GET test-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "top_10_test_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "test_field.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}

#top 10 test_field + top 10 status
GET test-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "top_10_test_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "test_field.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "top_10_test_field_and_top_10_status": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


You can use doc_count in the response body as result.
To fit to your example, replace servers instead of test_field and replace status instead of log.

In the above example we are using .keyword which is eligible for terms aggregation. Check your fields with the following _mapping API call and use eligible fields in the aggregation.
GET your_index_name/_mapping

If you have more than one indices you can use regex.
GET index-*/_mapping, GET index-*/_search

If you want to compare the size or count by index, you can use _cat/indices API call.
GET _cat/indices/index1,index2?v


